# Sobolev spaces embedding on $ R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

It's true this Sobolev spaces embedding?

if $ k < s $ then $ H^{s}(R^n)\hookrightarrow H^{k}(R^n) $ ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. This is a direct consequence of the $H^s$ norm being stronger than the $H^k$ norm for $s>k$.

Comment: In my Analysis class, we have proved this embedding in the case of $ H^s (T^n) $. I didn't know if it was possible to extend this embedding to the case of $ H^s (R^n) $. Thanks again for the answer.